# Trivialism vs Alethic Nihlism

Tags: logic, truth, philosophy-of-logic, propositional-logic, truth-conditional-semantics

What are the similiarities and differences between the two theories (as well as arguments for and counterarguments against).

From what I know, trivialism states that everything is true (and I believe they accept everything), while alethic nihlism believes that nothing is true or false although some things can be accepted and somethings can be rejected (whatever tf this even means).

So does this mean for trivialism, both sides of the T-schema are accepted while for alethic nihlism its always the left-side that gets rejected (it is not true but it is also somehow not false) but the right side depends on whether the scenario "is the case" although it "isn't true" (whatever that means)?

How do trivialism and alethic nihlism relate in logic?

Do trivialism believe that everything is true in logic (like p v not p = true p ^ not p = true). I think alethic nihlism believes that logic works the way its supposed to (p v not p = true and p ^ not p = false) they just deny using the words true or false outside of logic for whatever arbitrary reason.

Comment: They both believe that truth is a redundant concept in logic. Saying that nothing is true (or false) and saying that everything is true (and false) amounts to that. Perhaps worse, "truth" is misleading and creates technical problems. Trivialists accept the T-schema and nihilists reject it. Why? Adding the truth predicate to a language without elaborate precautions leads to inconsistency. Trivialists embrace it, and nihilists abhor it so much that they propose a radical surgery to excise it. The result is effectively the same - they make "truth" vacuous. Extremes converge.

Comment: Nihlists only deny half of T-schema. They only deny the T-schema where stuff is true but it is the case that stuff (whatever tf that means). They do acept the T-schema where stuff is not true but it is not the case that stuff. Also, apparently they state stuff is not true but its not false either (whatever tf that means).

Answer (score 1):

The *coherence theory of truth* would imply, I suppose, everything *is* true ... in some context (trivialism) . By the same token, everything is, unfortunately, *also* false ... in some, hopefully *other* context (aletheic nihilism)

This is old news to Jains of India though (re: *Anekantavada*), aka *perspectivism*, thereabouts.

Gordian knots I sense:

1. If everything is true then that everything is false is *also* true.
2. If everything is false then that everything is false is *also* false

Comment: Alethic nihlism states that nothing is true or false. I dont know wtf that means